# ¿Como puedo acomodar la información de un arreglo a una tabla dependiendo del pedido?

Tags: javascript, html5

Mi problema se trata de que el back me regresa un arreglo en donde viene la información de los pedidos de un usuario.
[image: arreglo de pedidos]

entonces vuando navego en el arreglo saco los datos y construyo las 8 tablas que necesito que son los pedidos del usuario, entonces en donde me falla, es a la hora de meter los productos de cada pedido a la tabla que corresponde, cuando se llenan las tablas sacando los productos me inserta bien los primeros 3 en la tabla que corresponde pero ya despues me va metiendo de 1 en 1 los productos en las siguientes tablas, alguien que me pudiera apoyar en como seria bueno sacar el resultado que busco se los agradeceria, les muestro mi codigo.

```js
//FUCNION MOSTRAR EQUIPOS=================================================================================
function abrirContenidoPedidos(){

  var htmlPedidosTotal = "";
  var htmlBodyPedidos = "";
  var htmlTituloPedido = "";

  var jsonData = {
    "platformType": "CerCrm"
  }

  showMessageOverlay("CARGANDO...", "<?=$pointer;?>images/cargando.gif", "200", "200", "sending");

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "<?=$pointer;?>backend/backend_partidas_pedidos_mostrar.php",
    data: jsonData,
    success:function(data){
      var resultadoMostrar = JSON.parse(data);
      if(resultadoMostrar["codigo"] == "fallo"){
        if(resultadoMostrar["mensaje"] == ""){
          $(".textoMensaje").text("ERROR.");
        }
        else{
          $(".textoMensaje").text(resultadoMostrar["mensaje"]);
        }

        $("#msj").modal("toggle");

        $(".contenidoUsuarioMonedero").html("");
        closeMessageOverlay();
      }
      else if(resultadoMostrar["codigo"] == "exito"){

        var resultadosPedidos = resultadoMostrar["objetoRespuesta"]["pedidos"];

        for(var i = 0; i < resultadosPedidos.length; i++) {

          var resultadoTotalEquipos = resultadosPedidos[i];

          for(var j = 0; j < resultadoTotalEquipos.length; j++) {
            var resultadoPedido = resultadoTotalEquipos[j];

            var informacion         = resultadoPedido["INFORMACION"];
            var nombreUsuarioPedido = resultadoPedido["NOMBRE"];
            var cantidad            = resultadoPedido["cantidad"];
            var idPartida           = resultadoPedido["idPartida"];
            var precioUnitario      = resultadoPedido["precioUnitario"];
            var total               = resultadoPedido["total"];


              htmlBodyPedidos += ""+
              "<tr class='resultados trHover' id='filasSelect'>"+
                "<td class='resultado'>"+informacion+"</td>"+
                "<td class='resultado'>"+cantidad+"</td>"+
                "<td class='resultado'>$"+precioUnitario+"</td>"+
                "<td class='resultado'>$"+total+"<input type='hidden' class='campoTotalPedido' value=''/></td>"+
              "</tr>";

            
          }

          htmlPedidosTotal += ""+
          "<div class='colLg18 colMd18 colSm24 colXs24' id='divPedidosGenerados'>"+
            "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form'>"+
              "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm tituloPartida'></div>"+
              "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff cuerpoForm'>"+
                "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form tabla'>"+
                  "<table id='tablaPedidosGenerados'>"+
                    "<tr class='encabezados'>"+
                      "<td class='encabezado'>INFORMACIÓN</td>"+
                      "<td class='encabezado'>CANTIDAD</td>"+
                      "<td class='encabezado'>PRECIO</td>"+
                      "<td class='encabezado'>TOTAL</td>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                    "<tbody class='contenidoPedido'>"+
                      htmlBodyPedidos+
                    "</tbody>"+
                  "</table>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24'>"+
                "<p class='etiquetasTextoMediano centerText totalPagoPedidos'></p>"+
                "<input type='hidden' class='sumaPedidoTotal'/>"+
                "</div>"+
              "</div>"+
            "</div>"+
          "</div>"+
          "<div class='colLg06 colMd06 colSm24 colXs24 form'>"+
            "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24'>"+
              "<br>"+
              "<button class='colLg12 colLgPush06 colMd12 colMdPush06 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00' onClick='abrirPopupPagoPedidos(this);'><span class='btnPagar'></span>PAGAR PEDIDO</button>"+
            "</div>"+
          "</div>  ";
          closeMessageOverlay();
          $(".tablasPedidos").html(htmlPedidosTotal);
        }

      }  
    }
  });    
}
//====================================================================================================

//EVENTO READY========================================================================================
$(document).ready(function(){
  abrirContenidoPedidos();
});
//====================================================================================================
```

```html
<div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form">
  <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm centerText" id="cuerpoCarrito1">
    <label class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24">PEDIDOS</label>
  </div>
  <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 tablasPedidos"></div>
</div>
```

[image: resultado de las tablas.]

Comment: No puedo probar muy bien porque es muy complicado con lo que pusiste... pero así mirando por encima el código... no tendras que hacer `htmlBodyPedidos = ""` en cada iteración del ciclo `i`? Estoy suponiendo que es por esto que se te repite todo en todas las tablas

Comment: Si, deecho tu respuesta es correcta es por eso, ya salio el resultado que buscaba igual pondre el resultado, muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//FUCNION MOSTRAR EQUIPOS=================================================================================
function abrirContenidoPedidos(){

  var htmlPedidosTotal = "";
  var htmlTituloPedido = "";

  var jsonData = {
    "platformType": "CerCrm"
  }

  showMessageOverlay("CARGANDO...", "<?=$pointer;?>images/cargando.gif", "200", "200", "sending");

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "<?=$pointer;?>backend/backend_partidas_pedidos_mostrar.php",
    data: jsonData,
    success:function(data){
      var resultadoMostrar = JSON.parse(data);
      if(resultadoMostrar["codigo"] == "fallo"){
        if(resultadoMostrar["mensaje"] == ""){
          $(".textoMensaje").text("ERROR.");
        }
        else{
          $(".textoMensaje").text(resultadoMostrar["mensaje"]);
        }

        $("#msj").modal("toggle");

        $(".contenidoUsuarioMonedero").html("");
        closeMessageOverlay();
      }
      else if(resultadoMostrar["codigo"] == "exito"){

        var resultadosPedidos = resultadoMostrar["objetoRespuesta"]["pedidos"];

        for(var i = 0; i < resultadosPedidos.length; i++) {

          var resultadoTotalEquipos = resultadosPedidos[i];

          var htmlBodyPedidos =
          "<tr class='resultados trHover' id='filasSelect'>"+
            "<td class='resultado'></td>"+
            "<td class='resultado'></td>"+
            "<td class='resultado'></td>"+
            "<td class='resultado'><input type='hidden' class='campoTotalPedido' value=''/></td>"+
          "</tr>";

          for(var j = 0; j < resultadoTotalEquipos.length; j++) {
            var resultadoPedido = resultadoTotalEquipos[j];

            var informacion         = resultadoPedido["INFORMACION"];
            var nombreUsuarioPedido = resultadoPedido["NOMBRE"];
            var cantidad            = resultadoPedido["cantidad"];
            var idPartida           = resultadoPedido["idPartida"];
            var precioUnitario      = resultadoPedido["precioUnitario"];
            var total               = resultadoPedido["total"];

            htmlBodyPedidos += 
            "<tr class='resultados trHover' id='filasSelect'>"+
              "<td class='resultado'>"+informacion+"</td>"+
              "<td class='resultado'>"+cantidad+"</td>"+
              "<td class='resultado'>$"+precioUnitario+"</td>"+
              "<td class='resultado'>$"+total+"<input type='hidden' class='campoTotalPedido' value='"+total+"'/></td>"+
            "</tr>";
          }

          htmlPedidosTotal += ""+
          "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24' id='divPedidosGenerados'>"+
            "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form'>"+
              "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm'>"+
                "<p class='etiquetasTextoMediano centerText'>PEDIDO - "+idPartida+"</p>"+
              "</div>"+
              "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff cuerpoForm'>"+
                "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form tabla'>"+
                  "<table id='tablaPedidosGenerados'>"+
                    "<tr class='encabezados'>"+
                      "<td class='encabezado'>INFORMACIÓN</td>"+
                      "<td class='encabezado'>CANTIDAD</td>"+
                      "<td class='encabezado'>PRECIO</td>"+
                      "<td class='encabezado'>TOTAL</td>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                    "<tbody class='contenidoPedido'>"+
                      htmlBodyPedidos+
                    "</tbody>"+
                  "</table>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24'>"+
                  "<p class='etiquetasTextoMediano centerText totalPagoPedidos'></p>"+
                  "<input type='hidden' class='sumaPedidoTotal'/>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24'>"+
                  "<br>"+
                  "<button class='colLg04 colLgPush10 colMd04 colMdPush10 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00' onClick='abrirPopupPagoPedidos(this);'><span class='btnPagar'></span>PAGAR PEDIDO</button>"+
                "</div>"+
              "</div>"+
            "</div>"+
          "</div>";
          closeMessageOverlay();
          $(".tablasPedidos").html(htmlPedidosTotal);
        }
      }  
    }
  });    
}
//====================================================================================================

//EVENTO READY========================================================================================
$(document).ready(function(){
  abrirContenidoPedidos();
});
//====================================================================================================
```

```html
<div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form">
  <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 tablasPedidos"></div>
</div>
```